# How do i submit login details from a c++ app to wordpress, and get the username/profile picture back

Tags: c++, .net, wordpress, visual-c++, managed-c++

I've set up a word press site (for now call it wpserver.com), and i want it so that i can send login details (to wpserver.com/wp-admin) via a c++ program, and get the username and profile picture back. If it's possible, is there a solution with the .net framework?

I have no idea what to do so kudos for any answer.

Comment: Wait... C++ and .NET? Are you using "managed C++", aka C++/CLI?

Comment: You could use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar yeah, sorry i didn't know the proper name, editing now

Comment: @ThomasSablik Not sure how to use it,but im reading the docs now

Comment: wordpress has a rest api (https://developer.wordpress.org/). search for a rest library that suits your platform needs. the visual C++ team has one that supports both windows and linux. WP does not have built in profile picture. if the site is using gravatar.com you can query by email.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Where exactly can i find the visual c++ API, i can't find it. This is also exactly what i need, so thanks in advance

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-c-rest-sdk-casablanca/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has a rust api. this means you can make wordpress based apps, and use wordpress features.
Thanks @ShengJiang蒋晟 for the answer

Visual C++ version: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=casablanca